# Change "not a real question" to post a comment like "must read FAQ"

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, not-a-real-question

There are multiple reasons why a question gets closed as "Not a real question".  I'd like the system to automatically post a link to the SO FAQ as a comment to the question when the first Not a Real Question vote is cast

Similar to when the system posts a link to questions being marked for closure due to "Exact Duplicate"

I think this would be very helpful to those that are new to the site.  And yes, I know a link to the FAQ is at the bottom of every page.  Although, interestingly, even though I've been a member here since it was first in Beta I'm pretty sure I never even looked at those links until recently... My mind keeps filtering them out as "advertising" ;)

**update**

A couple of Wording possibilities:

1. Please review the FAQ for hints on how to get great answers.
2. Please review the FAQ for the best way to ask questions.

Comment: I would think that would make the first close voter appear somewhat unfriendly. Do you have a proposed wording?

Comment: @John: updated with a couple of potential messages

Comment: That's good. +1. I just didn't want something condescending.

Comment: I don't think this should be a shown as a comment, however showing a link beflow the question in a hard to miss colour may be a good option

Comment: @John: I agree that a condescending tone doesn't work.  Heck, I've deleted two of *my own* comments today due to that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am not sure I agree with a comment here, but I agree it's crazy (in retrospect) that we don't link to the FAQ *in the close reason* e.g.

> #### closed as not a real question by Mitch Wheat, Icarus, Eranga, Joel Coehoorn, Graviton 1 hour ago
>
> It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form.

versus

> #### closed as not a real question by Mitch Wheat, Icarus, Eranga, Joel Coehoorn, Graviton 1 hour ago
>
> It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form. [See the FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#close).

We'll make that so -- add the last sentence there.